# How to dynamically change the Accordion elements in materialize's CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, materialize

I need to change the accordion elements  dynamically, while clicking `click Here to next accordion` button need to activate next accordion elements. But I tried many ways doesn't work anything. Can you please suggest me?

[**JSFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/78125vs0/120/)

```
    $('.collapsible').collapsible();
      $('.next-accordion').on('click', function(){
      $('#scondId').click();
      $('#scondId').trigger('click');
     });
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of triggering it on `li`'s id trigger it on the child element:

```
$('#scondId > div').click();
```

#### [Demo fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/78125vs0/121/)